# PHP, MYSQL and Jquery example with checkbox with Tree view

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, kendo-ui

I need a treeview checkbox using Jquery or Kendo treeview or any other, please find my data in the image.

Treeview is hierarchical, need 5 roots.

My requirement is little difficult to understand. Layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4 and layer5 are roots, test set name is the lase level. all unique levels are roots if layer5 is empty then test set name should be layer4. same for all layers also.

[Layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4 and layer5 are roots, test set name is last level.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wEGt.png)

MySQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `testlab_data` (
  `testlab_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Project` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `StatusCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RunStatus` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `TestSetName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Layer1` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Layer2` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Layer3` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Layer4` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Layer5` varchar(150) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `testlab_data` (`testlab_ID`, `Project`, `StatusCount`, `RunStatus`, `TestSetName`, `Layer1`, `Layer2`, `Layer3`, `Layer4`, `Layer5`) VALUES
(70001, 'xLos', 5, 'Blocked', 'Sprint 3_Regression', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 1.5 - Mass Code', 'Regression Testing', 'Add New WBS - Regression Test Suite', 'Sprint 3_Regression'),
(70002, 'xLos', 1, 'Blocked', 'US612 - WBS lines for Advisory', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US612 - WBS lines for Advisory'),
(70003, 'xLos', 2, 'Blocked', 'US629 - WBS Line for Firmwide', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US629 - WBS Line for Firmwide'),
(70004, 'xLos', 19, 'Blocked', 'US630-WBS lines for CR External', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US630 - WBS lines for CR External'),
(70005, 'xLos', 1, 'Blocked', 'US631 - WBS Line for Internal', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US631 - WBS Line for Internal'),
(70006, 'xLos', 4, 'Blocked', 'US661 - Approver Task List', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'Final Regression - IIB9', 'Regression Testing - Rel2.0', 'US718 - Approver Task'),
(70007, 'xLos', 2, 'Blocked', 'US690 - WBS Line for Caribbean Internal', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US690 - WBS Line for Caribbean Internal'),
(70008, 'xLos', 27, 'Blocked', 'US703 - Service Material', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US720 - Attributes for lines'),
(70009, 'xLos', 20, 'Blocked', 'US724-WBS lines for Assurance', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US724 - WBS lines for Assurance'),
(70010, 'xLos', 5, 'Blocked', 'US725-GDM and RAGDM Codes', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US724 - WBS lines for Assurance'),
(70011, 'xLos', 7, 'Blocked', 'US727-Profit Center for Assurance', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US724 - WBS lines for Assurance'),
(70012, 'xLos', 1, 'Blocked', 'US729 - Product code for Tax', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US628 - WBS lines for Tax'),
(70013, 'xLos', 4, 'Blocked', 'US730 - Profit center and Product code Derivation', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US630 - WBS lines for CR External'),
(70014, 'xLos', 5, 'Blocked', 'US746 - WBS Line for PD codes', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US746 - WBS Line for PD codes'),
(70015, 'xLos', 9, 'Failed', 'Sprint 3_Regression', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 1.5 - Mass Code', 'Regression Testing', 'Add New WBS - Regression Test Suite', 'Sprint 3_Regression'),
(70016, 'xLos', 3, 'Failed', 'Sprint 3_Regression', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'Final Regression - IIB9', 'Regression Testing - Release 1.0', 'Sprint 3_Regression'),
(70017, 'xLos', 1, 'Failed', 'Sprint 4_Regression', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 1.5 - Mass Code', 'Regression Testing', 'Add New WBS - Regression Test Suite', 'Sprint 4_Regression'),
(70018, 'xLos', 4, 'Failed', 'US612 - WBS lines for Advisory', 'US FIN - myEngage Automation Phase 2', 'Release 2.0 - Create Contract', 'System Testing', 'US604 - WBS codes', 'US612 - WBS lines for Advisory')
```

Can anybody help me on creating treeview using above data, just like attached image.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: This looks a lot like poor design, btw

Comment: Can you help me on creating treeview with check box like image.